# Mac OS X Awk - print input line and part of input line together

Tags: macos, awk

Having a file containing:

```
field1/field2/field3
```

how do you use awk to yield the following output?

```
field2 field1/field2/field3
```

On Linux: `awk -F '/' '{print $2 " " $_}'` is doing the job.

But the equivalent on Mac OS X: `awk -F '/' '{print $2 " " $0}'` is only printing the input line `$0`.

Comment: `$_` is only "doing the job" because you can create a variable named `_` so when awk sees `$_` it thinks you're trying to access the field whose number is stored in the variable named `_` and since that variable is uninitialized it has the value null-or-zero and so `$_` is treated as `$0` and prints the whole record. Never use `_` as a variable name unless you are trying to obfuscate your code. It is impossible for the second command you posted to only print the input line, it would at the very least prepend a blank char to it, but change the command to `print NF,"<"$2">","["$0"]"` to debug.

Comment: Thanks Ed, the debug proposal allows me to move on a little further. When I create a sample file from scratch, it is working, but on my real file it is not. I basically get "] <> [field1/field2..." ... I guess something is wrong with the file formatting. Still trying to figure out what exactly though ...

Comment: Don't try to put formatted text in a comment as you can't - edit your question to include the input and output and the script you ran. Hang on - I bet your input file was created on Windows and so contains spurious control-Ms that are messing up how the output looks. Use `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: It is not a Windows file. It is the result of a curl downloaded web page, from which lines are extracted and manipulated with sed to get a list of URLs. When I edit this list with vi and put :set list, I see a $ sign at the end of each line. Putting an explicit ^M at the end does not seem to make a difference. When I select lines and copy paste them in another file, then with that new file the awk is behaving correctly. I don't understand how with your debug suggestion, as of the the first line each line starts with ] instead of ending with it.

Comment: This is getting weird …
Awk command used: cat ToSplit.txt | awk -F '/' '{print NF, "<"$3">","["$0"]"}'
Original file called email.body
cp email.body ToSplit.txt -> awk fails
cat email.body > ToSplit.txt -> awk fails
vi ToSplit.txt; cat email.body >> ToSplit.txt -> awk fails
vi ToSplit.txt (add field1/field2/field3 - no enter at EOL); cat email.body >> ToSplit.txt; vi :%s/^V^M//g -> awk succeeds !
Why do ^M's get added only when already one line exists in ToSplit.txt? All other cases no ^M visible.

Comment: It REALLY sounds like you have control-Ms in the file already since after `vi :%s/^V^M//g` awk succeeds. idk what `set list` would do but I told you to use `cat -v` to see them - did you do that? You seem to think I'm suggesting you add control-Ms but I'm saying the opposite -I told you to use `dos2unix` or similar to remove them and your `s/../` command does that and afterwards the awk command succeeds, right?

Comment: Ed, I've worked around the problem now and I'm happy with that. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that your awk incantation (with `-F '/'`, or equivalently `-F/`) produces the correct results on a Mac with each of the following:

1. /usr/bin/awk version 20070501
2. gawk
3. mawk